# Generating ".dll" using Intel FORTRAN Compiler

Tags: dll

I have a .f90 file and respective .dll from service provider. I am generating .dll using Intel Fortran Compiler from the source file (.f90) but it is not being loaded into the software (PSS Netomac). I am creating a 32bit .dll and the master copy is also a 32 bit.

Can somebody please suggest a possible solution / way of doing so? I am en electrical engineer and don't know much about programming..

Thanking in advance.

Comment: [It is probably useful to put "intel-fortran" and "fortran" tag to get more visibility of this question... (then Dr.Fortran might look at this question.)]

Comment: Thanks for your consideration. I just got working results. :-)